# Array_walk и trim

Tags: php

```
$property = array(
  'File size                                ',
  ' 25.1 KiB',
);
array_walk($property, 'trim');
var_dump('<pre>' . var_export($property, true) . '</pre>');
```

**Результат:**

```
string(92) "
array (
  0 => 'File size                                ',
  1 => ' 25.1 KiB',
)
"
```

Что ниже делать — Вы знаете.

Comment: Что это за поток сознания и как он вяжется с направленностью ресурса? Напоминаю, ХэшКод - форум вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что array_walk не работает как нужно.

Comment: Она работала бы неправильно, если бы `trim()` принимала ссылку. В вашем варианте `array_walk` работает правильно.

Comment: @klopp, не правильно же, ну. Почему тогда результата нет?

Comment: А какой результат ожидается? `array_walk()` в вашем примере делает ровно то, что и должен: проходится по массиву и для элемента каждого вызывает `trim()`. Что результат `trim()` не присваивается потом этим элементам - так и не должен. В документации же ясно написано:


>If funcname needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of funcname as a reference. 


То есть хоть так:


    functiopn my_trim(&$s) 
    { 
        $s = trim($s); 
    } 
    array_walk($property,'my_trim');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё гениально просто!

```
$property = array_map('trim', $property)
```